# How to draw arrow head with coordinates?

Tags: c#, math, geometry, itext, coordinates

Is there a nice way to draw an arrowhead, when you have only coordinates of the source and destination point of the line?

[image: Image for reference]

So I'm using ITextSharp, programming in c#.
I know how to easily calculate slope and stuff but is there a way of calculating the edge coordinates for the "arrowhead" triangle (marked red in image)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Vague idea: Go to the end of the line, get the slope +-45 degrees, travel that direction for a particular distance. It'll require a bit of mathematics, but make sure you work out what you're doing on paper before you try and write it (to save yourself a headache)

Comment: Maybe try [How to add a map with a pointer to a PDF?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-map-pointer-pdf)

Comment: @LarsTech That's indeed the easiest way, but be aware that the example adds an annotation. We can't tell from the image if the arrow should be part of the content stream (in which case you *do* need to create the PDF syntax and calculate the coordinates), or if it can be an annotation, in which case you just define one end of the line as an arrowhead.

Comment: It has to be the pdfContentByte builded with MoveTo and LineTo, so Bruno is right, I can't use annotation

Comment: @Senderek Then it's just a matter of using high-school Math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your central line is vector from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)`

Backward direction vector `D = (dx, dy) = (x1-x2, y1-y2)`

Length of it: `Norm = Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)`

Normalize it: `uD = (udx, udy) = (dx/Norm, dy/Norm)`

To form "wings" of arrow, rotate `uD` by needed angle. For example, I use angle `Pi/6` with `Cos(Pi/6) = Sqrt(3)/2` and `Sin(Pi/6) = 1/2`

```
ax = udx * Sqrt(3)/2 - udy * 1/2
ay = udx * 1/2 + udy * Sqrt(3)/2
bx = udx * Sqrt(3)/2 + udy * 1/2
by =  - udx * 1/2 + udy * Sqrt(3)/2
```

Points for head with wing length `L=20`:

```
 (x1 + 20 * ax, y1 + 20 * ay) 
and
 (x1 + 20 * bx, y1 + 20 * by)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we define two (2-dimensional) vectors p2 and p3 for the end point of your line and the end point of one side of the arrow respectively you will get p3 by evaluating

p3 = p2 + A(alpha)s

s is a vector (l, 0) where l is the length of one side of the arrow.

alpha is the angle of this line against the x-axis i.e. the sum of the angle of your given line and the positive or negative angle between this line and the arrow line.

The components of the matrix are:

a11 = a22 = cos(alpha)

a12 = -sin(alpha)

a21 = sin(alpha)

Edit: As the y-component of s is zero a12 and a22 are not needed.