# Find coordinates for arrowhead

Tags: geometry

I have drawn a line (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and would now like to draw 2 more lines that would form an arrowhead at point (x2, y2). How do I determine the 2 points to which I need to draw the arrowheads from point (x2, y2)? I know that I need to find 2 points on a circle with center at point (x2, y2) that are equidistant from line (x1, y1), (x2, y2) but I do not know how to find this. Geometry is not my forte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line is vector from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2), its components are

```
D = (dx, dy) = (x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

Length of vector (perhaps you have Hypot function in math library):

```
Norm = Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
```

Normalized (unit length) vector:

```
uD = (udx, udy) = (dx/Norm, dy/Norm)
```

(again - math library might contain a function for normalized vector to replace two last formulas)

Unit perpendicular vector:

```
uP = (upx, upy) = (-udy, udx)
```

Now make two points at distance L along line from line end, and with perpendicular distance W from the line:

```
ax = x2 - udx * L + W * upx
ay = y2 - udy * L + W * upy

bx = x2 - udx * L - W * upx
by = y2 - udy * L - W * upy
```

[image]

At last draw lines A-P2 and B-P2

P.S. If you want to define arrow angle, `tg(alpha) = W/L`, also you can [look at calculations here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079770/844416)

Comment: Thank you for you help. This worked perfectly. The only thing is that there is a typo in the Unit Perpendicular Vector formula. This should be Thank you for you help. This worked perfectly. The only thing is that there is a typo in the Unit Perpendicular Vector formula. This should be:-

uP = (upx, upy) = (-udy, udx)